# Data frame error, trying to create heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a heatmap, similar to here. I'm using the same code. https://nitinahuja.github.io/2017/heatmaps-in-r/

Here's some example of the data:

```
    Date        Change  Hour    Day
1   2020-01-22  -0.01   02:00   Wednesday
2   2020-01-22  -0.24   01:00   Wednesday
3   2020-01-22  0.12    00:00   Wednesday
4   2020-01-21  0.16    23:00   Tuesday
5   2020-01-21  -0.12   22:00   Tuesday
6   2020-01-21  -0.02   21:00   Tuesday
7   2020-01-21  2.46    20:00   Tuesday
8   2020-01-21  -1.22   19:00   Tuesday
9   2020-01-21  -0.26   18:00   Tuesday
10  2020-01-21  0.1    17:00    Tuesday
11  2020-01-21  -0.07   16:00   Tuesday
12  2020-01-21  -0.1054 15:00   Tuesday
13  2020-01-21  -0.069  14:00   Tuesday
14  2020-01-21  0.0477  13:00   Tuesday
15  2020-01-21  -0.02   12:00   Tuesday
16  2020-01-21  -0.02   11:00   Tuesday
17  2020-01-21  0.34    10:00   Tuesday
18  2020-01-21  -0.22   09:00   Tuesday
19  2020-01-21  0.21    08:00   Tuesday
20  2020-01-21  -0.11   07:00   Tuesday
21  2020-01-21  -0.12   06:00   Tuesday
22  2020-01-21  -0.19329 5:00   Tuesday
23  2020-01-21  0.0213  4:00    Tuesday
24  2020-01-21  0.09    3:00    Tuesday
25  2020-01-21  0.1306  2:00    Tuesday
26  2020-01-21  0.1960  1:00    Tuesday
27  2020-01-21  -0.09   0:00    Tuesday
28  2020-01-20  -0.23   23:00   Monday
```

I have run the following code:

```
ggplot(Change , aes(x=Hour, y=Day, fill = Change)) + 
    geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.1) + 
    scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
    scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
    scale_fill_viridis(name="Price Change", option = "plasma") + 
    coord_equal() + 
    labs(x="Call hour", y=NULL, title=sprintf("price change by hr", vendor)) + 
    theme_tufte(base_family="Helvetica") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))'''
```

I've managed to get teh ggplot function working but the chart it produces is completely wrong.

Since I've got the same data essentially as given in the linked example and followed the same commands, I'm unsure where it has gone wrong. See image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwulV.png)

Comment: How did you import your data? Are you sure you saved it to a variable named `Change`? That's the variable name you are passing in to `ggplot()` as the data source. Also, does your real data have proper column headers?

Comment: I imported it using the Files tab on the right-hand side of R Studio. yes, I want to plot price change into a heatmap, to show the change by hour and by day. What do you mean by proper column headers? I think I do as the table is shown at the top with Date, Change, Hour and Day at the top.

Comment: Your data should be loaded as `Change` with column names as `Date`, `Change`, `Hour`, `Day`. Your data does not contain any column name.

Comment: How would I go about loading the data as Change? I only know how to use the Files tab to import data. rename the file?

Comment: It's good to know how to read data in R, rather than relying on clicking a helper button in RStudio, for precisely this reason. You'll have a hard time doing anything else if you can't get your data in place with workable column names. What you've posted doesn't have any names shown, although I'm guessing that's not the case with what you're working with...?

Comment: Alright, I've changed the file name but now I get this error: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale, when trying to plot the chart...

Comment: The column names are added, I forgot to add them here. I know how to structure data in R, but I keep getting errors whenever I try to do something after researching

Comment: The "Error: Discrete values supplied to continuous scale" most probably comes from the fact that the variable "Hour" is numeric in your file, and therefore the x-scale does not have discrete values. To get that, you need to transform your variable from numeric to factor. If you want to keep the numeric variable, you must use "scale_x_continuous" instead of scale_x_discrete.

Comment: Please provide the output of `str(Change)`. I'm guessing that it is your variable "Change" that has been converted either as a factor or a character variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the heatmap you are looking for ?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(df , aes(x=Hour, y=Day, fill = Change)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.1) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name="Price Change", option = "plasma") + 
  coord_equal() + 
  #labs(x="Call hour", y=NULL, title=sprintf("price change by hr", vendor)) + 
  theme_tufte(base_family="Helvetica") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

The only modification, I made is to replace `scale_fill_viridis` by `scale_fill_viridis_c`.

The dataframe (called `df` here) that I used as the following structure:

```r
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  28 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ROw   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Date  : chr  "2020-01-22" "2020-01-22" "2020-01-22" "2020-01-21" ...
 $ Change: num  -0.01 -0.24 0.12 0.16 -0.12 -0.02 2.46 -1.22 -0.26 0.1 ...
 $ Hour  : chr  "02:00" "01:00" "00:00" "23:00" ...
 $ Day   : chr  "Wednesday" "Wednesday" "Wednesday" "Tuesday" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

You can compare with your own data.frame by doing:

```r
str(Change)
```

If you see that the column "change" is marked as "chr", convert it to a numerical format by doing:

```
Change$Change <- as.numeric(Change$Change)
```

If is is marked as a factor, convert it to a numeric format by doing:

```r
Change$Change <- as.numeric(as.character(Change$Change))
```

**Data example:**

```r
structure(list(ROw = 1:28, Date = c("2020-01-22", "2020-01-22", 
"2020-01-22", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", 
"2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", 
"2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", 
"2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", 
"2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-21", 
"2020-01-20"), Change = c(-0.01, -0.24, 0.12, 0.16, -0.12, -0.02, 
2.46, -1.22, -0.26, 0.1, -0.07, -0.1054, -0.069, 0.0477, -0.02, 
-0.02, 0.34, -0.22, 0.21, -0.11, -0.12, -0.19329, 0.0213, 0.09, 
0.1306, 0.196, -0.09, -0.23), Hour = c("02:00", "01:00", "00:00", 
"23:00", "22:00", "21:00", "20:00", "19:00", "18:00", "17:00", 
"16:00", "15:00", "14:00", "13:00", "12:00", "11:00", "10:00", 
"09:00", "08:00", "07:00", "06:00", "5:00", "4:00", "3:00", "2:00", 
"1:00", "0:00", "23:00"), Day = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Monday")), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55aee5c44350>)
```

Comment: Do you know how I can change the order of the day of the week on the legend so it's in chronological order?

Comment: Before plotting, you can pass this command: `df$Day = factor(df$Day, levels = c("Wednesday","Tuesday","Monday"))`